# Two local node servers and proxying traffic based on specified path

Tags: node.js, nginx, npm, proxy

Im looking for a way to do the following:

Given two servers running locally on different ports:

- `localhost:3001`
- `localhost:3002`

I would like a third server running on port `3000` to route all traffic to `localhost:3001` except for specific whitelisted paths. I would like a configuration file to specify the paths. For example.

```
* localhost:3001
/example localhost:3002
```

In this case all traffic is proxying to `3001`, except for the route `/example` which will proxy to `localhost:3002/example`.

I do not want a redirect off of `3000` for any requests. I would like this intermediary server to appear to the only site. So I believe I would like the server running on port `3000` to be a proxy to the other two.

I am interested in doing this via `nginx` or a node.js / npm module if available. Is this possible? What is a simple way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx should suite perfectly for this job.
Usually it is used as a web tier for application servers located on other machines, but technically there's nothing different there from using the same host with different ports.

you should simply define `localhost:3002` and `localhost:3001` as the proxy_paths in your nginx configuration.

If you're not familiar with nginx, this can be a good place to start:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/